# How to remove view larger map icon from an iframe embeded google map

Tags: html, jquery, css

i want to remove the view larger map button from  the google map loaded in popup in an i frame is there a way to do this .
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are not able to do it with an `<iframe>` tag.

Here is the list of official parameters supported by Google Maps iframes:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-started

You can remove `allowfullscreen` to block the full screen mode, but I don't see any possibility to hide "View larger map" button.

You can't hide that button with CSS or JS (jQuery) on your website because access to body of an iframe is blocked for safety reasons (CORS policy).

You definitely can do it with Google Maps JavaScript API, but it requires an API key and  some coding.

In theory Static Map: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/overview could work for you, but it creates a static image so user can't zoom in or move the map.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="" style="
      height: 65vh;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    ">
  <div style="
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: calc(100vw + 600px);
      ">
    <iframe class="border-card" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d1877201.646144031!2d91.52807767106037!3d23.228182322195394!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x374d0bd19f3f36f7%3A0xb1f62692a3d5e474!2sMizoram!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1681814341442!5m2!1sen!2sin"
      width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a workaround, Hide the card area using overflow hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the solution above, I ended up using a solution like this, just shift the map 35 pixels up.

```html
    function loadGoogleMap(container) {
            // Create the outer div
        var outerDiv = document.createElement('div');
        outerDiv.style.cssText = "height: 15vh; overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: center;";

        // Create the inner div
        var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
        innerDiv.style.cssText = "position: absolute; bottom: 35px; height: 100%; width: 200px;";

        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.width = '180'; // Set the width
        iframe.height = '215'; // Set the height
        iframe.style.border = '0';
        iframe.loading = 'lazy';
        iframe.referrerpolicy = 'no-referrer-when-downgrade';
        var location = container.getAttribute('data-map-location'); // Get the unique URL
        // this is the personal key from a contractor, this key only enables the embed maps api
        iframe.src = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=" + location + "&key=key";
        // Append the iframe to the inner div
        innerDiv.appendChild(iframe);

        // Append the inner div to the outer div
        outerDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);

        // Append the outer div to the container
        container.appendChild(outerDiv);
    }
```